# We have a box with three different colors of balls. 8 green, n blue and 4 red...

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

We have a box  with three different colors of balls. 8 green, n blue and 4 red. We chose 3 at random. For each blue we gain 2 points, for each green we lose 1 point, and nothing happens with the red ones. Write the probability function and calculate the expectation of profit.

What have I managed to do so far

b = blue, g = green and r = red

the possible ways to remove the 3 balls are

$A_1 = b, b, b = 6. P[ x = 6]   \frac{\binom{n}{3}}{\binom{12+n}{3}} = \frac{\frac{1}{6} (-2 + n) (-1 + n) n}{\frac{1}{6} (10 + n) (11 + n) (12 + n)}= \frac{B_1}{B_0}$

$A_2 = b,b,r=4. P[ x = 4]      \frac{\binom{n}{2}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{12+n}{3}} = \frac{2 (-1 + n) n }{\frac{1}{6} (10 + n) (11 + n) (12 + n)}= \frac{B_2}{B_0}$

$A_3 = g,b,b=3. P[ x = 3]    \frac{\binom{n}{2}\binom{8}{1}}{\binom{12+n}{3}} = \frac{4(-1 + n) n }{\frac{1}{6} (10 + n) (11 + n) (12 + n)}= \frac{B_3}{B_0}$

$A_4 = b,r,r=2. P[ x = 2]     \frac{\binom{n}{1}\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{12+n}{3}} = \frac{6n }{\frac{1}{6} (10 + n) (11 + n) (12 + n)}= \frac{B_4}{B_0}$

$A_5 = b,g,r=1. P[ x = 1]    \frac{\binom{n}{1}\binom{8}{1}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{12+n}{3}} = \frac{32n }{\frac{1}{6} (10 + n) (11 + n) (12 + n)}= \frac{B_5}{B_0}$

$A_6 = r,r,r=0, or, g,g,b=0. P[ x = 0]    \frac{\binom{4}{2}+ \binom{8}{2}\binom{n}{1}}{\binom{12+n}{3}} = \frac{34n}{\frac{1}{6} (10 + n) (11 + n) (12 + n)}= \frac{B_6}{B_0}$

$A_7 = g,r,r=-1. P[ x = -1]  \frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{8}{1}}{\binom{12+n}{3}} = \frac{48}{\frac{1}{6} (10 + n) (11 + n) (12 + n)}= \frac{B_7}{B_0}$

$A_8 = g,g,r=-2. P[ x = -2]  \frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{12+n}{3}} = \frac{112 }{\frac{1}{6} (10 + n) (11 + n) (12 + n)}= \frac{B_8}{B_0}$

$A_9 = g, g, g= -3. P[ x = -3]  \frac{\binom{8}{3}}{\binom{12+n}{3}} = \frac{56 }{\frac{1}{6} (10 + n) (11 + n) (12 + n)}= \frac{B_9}{B_0}$

Profit

$\frac{B_1+ B_2+ B_3+ B_4+ B_5}{B_0} = \frac{\frac{1}{6} (-2 + n) (-1 + n) n + 2 (-1 + n) n + 4(-1 + n) n + 6n + 32n }{\frac{1}{6} (10 + n) (11 + n) (12 + n)}$

is my reasoning correct?

thanks for any help.

Comment: A bit hard to follow. Note that it is easy to compute the expectation.  Each draw is expected to earn $\frac {2\times n-1\times 8}{n+12}$ points, so by linearity $E=3\times \frac {2 n- 8}{n+12}$.

Answer (score 2):

I find that the actual profit assigned to different colors distracts from a simpler way of looking at this. Imagine instead that you are given $N$ balls and each ball has an assigned value $b_i$ (not necessarily all distinct. Now, we do the same thing, we choose $3$ balls at random, say they are balls $i$, $j$ and $k$ and get the corresponding profit $b_i + b_j + b_k$. Let $B$ denote the set of balls, i.e. the values from $1$ to $N$.

Now if we want the expectation, we simply sum over all possible choices:
$$
E = \frac 1{N \choose 3}\sum_{\{i, j, k\} \subseteq B} b_i + b_j + b_k
$$

Now notice that in fact each $b_i$ value is counted $N - 1 \choose 2$ times in the sum, so we can rewrite the expected profit as
$$
E = \frac{N - 1 \choose 2}{N \choose 3} \sum_{i \in B} b_i = \frac 3{N}\sum_{i \in B} b_i
$$

Going back to your case, there are a total of $N = n + 12$ balls and the sum of their values is $2n - 8$ so the result becomes
$$
E = \frac 3{n + 12} \cdot (2n - 8)
$$

Comment: It should be $n+12$ at the denominator. If we want to keep things even simpler, we just consider the expected value of one ball being $\frac{2n}{n+12} - \frac{8}{n+12}$ and multiply by 3 because of linearity of expectation.

Comment: Indeed, the two methods must agree and the mistake was on my side. Notice when we count how many times the same $b_i$ value appears in the sum, the correct value is $N-1 \choose 2$ and not $N \choose 2$ because we must not count $b_i$. With that correction the results are the same.